# Doctrine Migrations in Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine

I need do something like this:

1. Load fixtures (add `10` records to table with names '`test0`'-'`test9`').
2. Load migrations and create loop for find this records and then rename them to '`category0`'-'`category9`'.
3. if '`changetest0`' was found before - then skip, if not found - then create.

My code (i think its not correct):

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $name = 'test' . $i;
            $category = $em->getRepository(Category::class)->findByName($name);
            if (isset($category) && $category == '') {
                $category->setName('category' . $i);
                $em->persist($category);
                $em->flush();
            } elseif ($em->getRepository(Category::class)->findByName('category' . $i)->getName() == 'category' . $i) {
                return;
            } else {
                $category->setName('category' . $i);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }
```

Any idea, how to do this correctly?

Comment: `Load fixtures (add 10 records....` where are you adding this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missing this:

You don't use `EntityManager` as `service`. Use `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`;

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $name = 'test' . $i;
    $category = $em->getRepository(Category::class)->findByName($name);
    if($category instanceof Category && !is_null($category)){
        $category->setName('category' . $i);
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();
    }
    //After if else you have to set `$category` to `null`
    $category = null;
}
```